# Make text overflow visible on hover using react, CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an array of divs containing book names that I generate using a `.map` function on some fetched data from my database. Some of the book names are too long so I have used the following CSS to hide them:

```
.book-title{
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 1.5rem;
    max-width: 15rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 0.7rem;
}
```

But I would like to make the text visible when user hovers over the div. My current solution applies to all divs generated and displayed by the `.map` function - I am unsure how to make it just apply to divs where the text is too long.

```
.book-title:hover{
  height: 6rem;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Is there a proper way to do this with react?

here is the relevant `.jsx`

```
 const listsForFrontPage = listArray.map((book, id) => {
    return (
      <Link className="book-link" to={`/books/${book.book_id}`} key={id}>
        <div className="book-card">
          <div className="book-card-image">
            <img
              className="cover-image"
              src={book.cover_image}
              alt="The book cover"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="book-info">
            <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
            <div className="author-name">{book.name}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    )
  })
```

Comment: your code seems good what is the problem

Comment: Even divs that don't have any actual over flowing text will have the hover effect applied, I am not sure how or where to isolate only divs where the text overflows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the element is overflowing

add useRef:

```
const refs = useRef(listArray.map(() => React.createRef()));
```

then you should create a function that checks if the element is overflowing:

```
  const isOverflown = (el) => {
    if(!el) return;
    const { clientWidth, clientHeight, scrollWidth, scrollHeight } = el;
    return scrollHeight > clientHeight || scrollWidth > clientWidth;
  }
```

and then you need to add class based on isOverflown value:

```
 const listsForFrontPage = listArray.map((book, id) => {
    return (
      <Link className="book-link" to={`/books/${book.book_id}`} key={id}>
        <div className="book-card">
          <div className="book-card-image">
            <img
              className="cover-image"
              src={book.cover_image}
              alt="The book cover"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="book-info">
            <div ref={refs.current[id]} className={`book-title ${isOverflown(refs.current[id].current) ? 'book-title-overflow' : ''}`}>{book.title}</div>
            <div className="author-name">{book.name}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    )
  })
```

don't forget to add your css:

```
.book-title-overflow:hover{
  height: 6rem;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. When I try this I get this error: ```Lists.jsx:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'clientWidth' of '_ref' as it is null.```

Comment: @deadant88 i have edited the isOverflown function. now it should work.